# MyEclipse,Java - Web Application Newbie

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am a newbie trying to create a sample web application using;

MySQL
Java
Tomcat
JSP & Servlet

The ide I use is MyEclipse Blue Edition.

The persistence and service layer is done. Within web layer however I'm having trouble displaying the index.jsp, here is what I done so far, and what my expectations are:

- I have associated the project with tomcat 6, each time I run the
  project service is stopped and restarted the final line in log is
  INFO: Server startup in x ms
- I have created the web layer by selecting new web project from which
  an example index.jsp was already genereated in web root folder, I
  also checked that in web.xml ( I suppose this is going to be used by
  tomcat ) there is a tag called welcome-list indicating the first
  jsp that should be opened when the application starts. index.jsp is on that list.
- I have used a tutorial on how to use Servlets and extended
  HTTPServlet within a class at web layer, presently it does very
  little things, namely within index.jsp there is a button, upon
  clicking that button this class should forward request and responses
  and open up another jsp file, this I couldn't test yet.

Which brings us to my newbie question: Everytime I run the project server starts and then nothing happens. I'm expecting for MyEclipse to start displaying index.jsp on its own browser from which I can copy/paste the url to a regular browser. I'm expecting the  url to be something like localhost:8080/index.jsp (tomcat runs on port 8080, in my computer).

Server seems to be running and I have tried different combinations but I can't seem ot display the index.jsp, whatever I try it is not found, what should I do ?

Edit1: Here is my web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is my servlet code: (I didn't get to test it so far, my main problem is not here)

```
public class CRMServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

String action =  request.getParameter("action");
System.out.println("ACTION : " + action);

if(action.equals("LoginRequest"))
{
    request.setAttribute("bilgi", "cem");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the Window tab and select web browser. there you can define your favorite browser.
2. For URL it should be like `http://localhost:8080/{ProjectName}/index.jsp`
   -- you can find the ProjectName with your IDE, with what name did u create the project
3. for servlet URL's check the `web.xml`, and to the same URL you have to pass in the form action tag.
   so that button click will go to servlet `doGet()` method and use `RequestDispatcher` to forward to another jsp.

web.xml

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

remove / from your `web.xml`, and i think you are not created the `servlet` by right click on your source folder, if you create the `servlet` by right click on the source folder, the entry of the servlet would be there in `web.xml` with `<servlet></servlet>` tag

Comment: When I run the project tomcat 6 begin to work at location:
localhost:8080 - I have default page - "If you are seeing this tomcat works.."
project name - 573PresentationLayer
at the following pages I have 404
localhost:8080/573PresentationLayer,
localhost:8080/573PresentationLayer/index.jsp,
localhost:8080/573PresentationLayer/WebRoot,
localhost:8080/573PresentationLayer/WebRoot/index.jsp

Comment: it means you are not configured your web.xml properly, can you give your web.xml code, as well as your servlet code.

Comment: I have concentrated on my web.xml as you have told, and solved the problem by altering it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The path you are trying to view is INCORRECT...

path should be

`localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.jsp` or `localhost:8080/ProjectName/`

`ProjectName` is the name of the project that you are doing... (same can be seen at the left side of Eclipse under **Projects**)

Please run above path and let me know for further queries....

Also are you cleaning and building the project or not ??

Comment: yes, thank you for your answer but it can not find anything there as well, 404 error